# I update ObservableCollection List but UI is not updating issue from Tab Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I update ObservableCollection List but UI is not updating from Tab Page
I also clear List then Assign new list, Value of list is change but UI is not updated

```
public ObservableCollection<Dashboard> DetailsList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Dashboard>();
    //API Call
    details = await _clientAPI.getDashboardDetails(id);
    if (details != null)
    {
        DetailsList.Clear();
        foreach (var item in details)
        {
            DetailsList.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss to binding the context. Add the code below.

```
  this.BindingContext = this;
```

I make a code sample for your reference. I am not sure what your Model, I use a simple model to test.

Page1.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Dashboard> DetailsList { get; set; }
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DetailsList = new ObservableCollection<Dashboard>()
        {
            new Dashboard(){ Name="AA", Country="CountryA"},
            new Dashboard(){ Name="BB", Country="CountryB"},

        };
        this.BindingContext = this;

    }

    private void btnUpdate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Dashboard> details = new List<Dashboard>();
        details.Add(new Dashboard() { Name = "CC", Country = "CountryC" });
        details.Add(new Dashboard() { Name = "DD", Country = "CountryD" });

        if (details != null)
        {
            DetailsList.Clear();
            foreach (var item in details)
            {
                DetailsList.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Dashboard
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

}
```

Xaml:

```
   <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button
            x:Name="btnUpdate"
            Clicked="btnUpdate_Clicked"
            Text="Update" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Country}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

**Updated:**

[image]

Comment: This is working well in normal page but in a tabbed page its not working

Comment: The same code i test on tabbed page, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ObservableCollection<Dashboard> DetailsList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Dashboard>();
    //API Call
    details = await _clientAPI.getDashboardDetails(id);
    if (details != null)
    {
        DetailsList.Clear();
        foreach (var item in details)
        {
            DetailsList.Add(item);
        }
    }

    YourGridView.ItemSource =DetailsList;
```

> YourGridView.ItemSource =DetailsList

You are missing this line. This code  - it just assigns ObservableCollection to gridview (which you want to display the data)

Thanks!!!